# Bass Audio Library on/off Button

Tags: inno-setup

How can i create on/off music button in this example:

[Playing sound during an Inno Setup install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359859/playing-sound-during-an-inno-setup-install)

I want use a image.png.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following script makes a button, by which you can play or pause the stream according to its current state:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=Bass Audio Project
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Bass Audio Project

[Files]
Source: "Bass.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "AudioFile.mp3"; Flags: dontcopy

[CustomMessages]
SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOn=Music on
SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff=Music off

[Code]
const  
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD; 
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: string; offset1: DWORD; 
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Start: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Start@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Pause: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Pause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): BOOL; 
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Free: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Free@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  SoundStream: HSTREAM;
  SoundCtrlButton: TNewButton;

procedure SoundCtrlButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) of
    BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING: 
    begin
      if BASS_Pause then
        SoundCtrlButton.Caption := 
          ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOn}');
    end;
    BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED: 
    begin
      if BASS_Start then
        SoundCtrlButton.Caption :=
          ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff}');
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    SoundStream := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False);

    SoundCtrlButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
    SoundCtrlButton.Parent := WizardForm;
    SoundCtrlButton.Left := 8;
    SoundCtrlButton.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
      SoundCtrlButton.Height - 8;
    SoundCtrlButton.Width := 155;
    SoundCtrlButton.Caption :=
      ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff}');
    SoundCtrlButton.OnClick := @SoundCtrlButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  BASS_Free;
end;
```

Comment: I'll appreciate any feedback... You know, it's the only motivation I'm having here for writing specific solutions like this. I've spent certain amount of time to write it and now I have just one upvote for it with no feedback from you. It doesn't make me satisfied from what I've done and for the next time I'll think twice before I'll invest my time for something like this ;-)

Comment: Dear TLama, how are you doing man? Sorry my delay to response your tips, i was out on a little trip. Your script above work perfectly, however, i want use a PNG button in my installer. Currently, i use this script [link]http://s17.postimage.org/mh7eadvn3/Sem_t_tulo.jpg .But if my volume of windows sound is 30%, when i rum my installer, it go to 100% automatcally. Based on script that i showed to you, how can i fix the problem? Thanks in advance and sorry one more time  by my delay to response.