# Inno Setup : Loop Audio File Using BASS Audio Library's All Functions and Flags

Tags: inno-setup, bass

Hello I know how to add a continuous music loop during an Inno Setup Install using BASS Audio Library.

- [BASS Audio Library On/Off Button.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770667/bass-audio-library-on-off-button)

But in this post, (which made me decide to use BASS.dll to do a continuous music loop during my Inno Setup Install), doesn't seems to be defined all flags supported by `BASS.dll.`

*When I used the code described in this post, BASS Audio Library doesn't loop the playing MP3 File.
It restarts the playback after the file completed playing successfully.
Also second start takes more than 2 seconds.
This is not a loop as I think.To be a loop, the audio file must continue re-playing with minimum gaps.*

*This post only defined `EncodingFlag` and `BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP` Flags to used with Pascal Script of Inno Setup.*

*But there seems to be more useful flags that can be used with `BASS.dll` such as `BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT`,`BASS_SAMPLE_PRESCAN`.*

- [BASS Audio Library Supported Flags.](http://bass.radio42.com/help/html/e49e005c-52c0-fc33-e5f9-f27f2e0b1c1f.htm)

I don't know how to define all Flags that supported by `BASS.dll` in Inno Setup like :

```
[Code]
const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
```

*How can I define all Flags supported by `BASS.dll`?*

***I want to know this because I want to loop my MP3 Audio File after a specified time continuously.***

***Not to continuously loop from file's beginning to end.***

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same syntax as you have in your question to define the additional flags.

Values of the additional flags are defined here:
http://bass.radio42.com/help/html/fdf43f28-d1cd-2951-c126-3ce35edaa7f5.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me their values ......But Why can't I use like `procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, WizardForm.Handle, 0);
  SoundStream := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\music.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0 ,BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
  BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 1500);
  BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False);
end;` ? Changing code like this makes `BASS` won't play anything.I only removed the `EncodingFlag` Flag.

Comment: I assume you have to set the "unicode" flag in Unicode version of Inno Setup.

Comment: Ahh Okay you mean if I set any flag for `BASS.dll`, I must combine it with `EncodingFlag`.Thank You.I will do the rest and notify you what happened.

Comment: Thanks all Flags working now.........I like to know what Flag can I use with `BASS` to loop my MP3 File after a specified time continuously as I asked in question? Like mentioning a specified looping time?

Comment: What makes you believe there's some magic flag for that? It's even technically not possible. A flag is just yes/no, it cannot hold a value (timeout). Looks like you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should probably ask a question for your real problem, without assuming some solution. Though I would start by double-checking that there is no 2s silent interval in the MP3 itself.

Comment: Okay okay however thank you for giving value list. :)