# How to mute audio (change volume) with BASS library in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

This code from [Bass Audio Library on/off Button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14770667/850848) does "Pause", how to change it to "Mute"?

What should I change?

```pascal
const  
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD; 
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: string; offset1: DWORD; 
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Start: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Start@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Pause: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Pause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): BOOL; 
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Free: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Free@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  SoundStream: HSTREAM;
  SoundCtrlButton: TNewButton;

procedure SoundCtrlButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) of
    BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING: 
    begin
      if BASS_Pause then
        SoundCtrlButton.Caption := 
          ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOn}');
    end;
    BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED: 
    begin
      if BASS_Start then
        SoundCtrlButton.Caption :=
          ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff}');
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('tune.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    SoundStream := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\tune.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False);

    SoundCtrlButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
    SoundCtrlButton.Parent := WizardForm;
    SoundCtrlButton.Left := 8;
    SoundCtrlButton.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
      SoundCtrlButton.Height - 8;
    SoundCtrlButton.Width := 40;
    SoundCtrlButton.Caption :=
      ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff}');
    SoundCtrlButton.OnClick := @SoundCtrlButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  BASS_Free;
end;
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Do you just want to change *"pause"* text to *"mute"* text? Or do you really want to implement "mute" functionality, as setting a volume to 0%, instead of actually pausing the media? But that does not make sense with audio-only media (.mp3), right? - Anyway, your code works for me. - Show us your `[Files]` section. What `bass.dll` did you use?

Comment: `"mute" functionality, as setting a volume to 0%`, is it possible? I use [un4seen](http://www.un4seen.com/) `bass.dll`

Comment: See my answer. But first, you need to make the code you already have working. You have some problem there. But that's a different topic. It works for me.

Comment: And still I do not understand, what's the point of "muting" audio-only media. I've never seen that.

Comment: BB's setup tune is _pause_ [Button `Music On / Music Off`] - While RLD's _stop_ [Button `Play / Mute`]. I want mine to mute. Sorry for demanding hehe

Comment: I do not know what RLD and BB is. What's the point is keeping musing playing with 0% volume? You are just wasting system resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control volume level, use the [`BASS_SetConfig`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_SetConfig.html) with `option` set to:

- [`BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM.html) for "stream", created e.g. using the [`BASS_StreamCreateFile`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_StreamCreateFile.html);
- [`BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_MUSIC`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_MUSIC.html) for "music", created e.g. using [`BASS_MusicLoad`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_MusicLoad.html).

The `SoundCtrlButtonClick` is replacement for the pause/resume implementation of the same-named function from your question.

```pascal
var
  Muted: Boolean;

procedure SoundCtrlButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Muted then
  begin
    if BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 0) then
    begin
      SoundCtrlButton.Caption := 'unmute'; 
      Muted := True;
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    if BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500) then
    begin
      SoundCtrlButton.Caption := 'mute'; 
      Muted := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Got it! :D Thanks!