# Prevent button from receiving focus in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In my script, when the audio button is clicked, it receives a focus (*That blue thick border*)

[image: My output]

---

I want it to be, even when you click the audio button, the focused button is still the *"Next/Install"*.

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to implement due to a lack of `OnEnter` event in Inno Setup API.

First, you want to set `TabStop` property of the button to `False` to prevent the button from receiving focus using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

```pascal
Button.TabStop := False;
```

*([In your case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40469833/850848), it's the `SoundCtrlButton`).*

If you are happy with focus always going back to the *"Next"* button, when it's mouse-clicked, it's easy. Just set the focus explicitly to the *"Next"* button at the end of the button's `OnClick` handler:

```pascal
procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Some actual code

  // If the button is focused
  // (it won't be, when access key was used to "click" it) ...
  if TButton(Sender).Focused then
    // ... focus the "Next" button
    WizardForm.ActiveControl := WizardForm.NextButton;
end;
```

*(In your case, the `OnClick` handler is `SoundCtrlButtonClick`).*

---

Though, if you want to implement this nicely, by returning the focus back to the control that actually had the focus previously, it's more difficult.

I cannot think of better solution than scheduling a frequent timer to monitor the focused control.

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(hWnd: LongWord; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord; 
  lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  LastFocusedControl: TWinControl;
  
procedure FocusMonitorProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  // Remember focused control, unless the currently focused control is
  // already the one, we do not want to get focused
  if (WizardForm.ActiveControl = nil) or
     WizardForm.ActiveControl.TabStop then
  begin
    LastFocusedControl := WizardForm.ActiveControl;
  end;
end;

procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Some actual code

  // If the button is focused
  // (it won't be, when access key was used to "click" it) ...
  if TButton(Sender).Focused and (LastFocusedControl <> nil) then
    { ... focus the previously focused control }
    WizardForm.ActiveControl := LastFocusedControl;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // Set up 50ms timer to monitor the focus
  SetTimer(0, 0, 50, CreateCallback(@FocusMonitorProc));  

  // Create the "unfocusable" button
  SomeButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  // Initialize button
  SomeButton.TabStop := False;  
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

---

Alternative solution is to use a button-like image (the [`TBitmapImage` control](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TBitmapImage)), instead of the actual `TButton`. The `TBitmapImage` control (not being the [`TWinControl`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWinControl)) cannot receive focus at all.

And it can actually get you a nice "mute" image instead of the plain *"Mute"* caption.