# Inno Setup: "Cannot focus disabled or invisible window" while setting ActiveControl property

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to focus a button in a custom options window, which is shown modally. I have already read [Prevent button from receiving focus in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494465/prevent-button-from-receiving-focus-in-inno-setup) and tried the use the `ActiveControl` property to set this. Here is the code:

```pascal
[Code]

{ Create and show the Options window }
procedure ShowOptionsWindow;
var
  OptionsOKButton, OptionsCancelButton: TButton;
begin
  OptionsWindowForm := TForm.Create(WizardForm);
  with OptionsWindowForm do
    begin
      Parent := WizardForm;
      BorderStyle := bsDialog;
      Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
      ClientWidth := ScaleX(425);
      ClientHeight := ScaleY(165);
      Caption := '{#AppName} Options';
    end;
{ Define the Options Cancel button }
  OptionsCancelButton := TButton.Create(OptionsWindowForm);
  with OptionsCancelButton do
    begin
      Parent := OptionsWindowForm;
      Left := (OptionsWindowForm.ClientWidth - WizardForm.NextButton.Width) - (WizardForm.ClientWidth - (WizardForm.CancelButton.Left + WizardForm.CancelButton.Width));
      Top := (OptionsWindowForm.ClientHeight - WizardForm.NextButton.Height) - ScaleY(12);
      Width := WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
      Height := WizardForm.NextButton.Height;
      Caption := 'Cancel';
      OnClick := @OptionsCancelButtonClick;
    end;
{ Define the Options OK button }
  OptionsOKButton := TButton.Create(OptionsWindowForm);
  with OptionsOKButton do
    begin
      Parent := OptionsWindowForm;
      Left := (OptionsCancelButton.Left - WizardForm.NextButton.Width) - ((WizardForm.CancelButton.Left - WizardForm.NextButton.Left) - WizardForm.NextButton.Width);
      Top := OptionsCancelButton.Top;
      Width := WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
      Height := WizardForm.NextButton.Height;
      Caption := 'OK';
      OnClick := @OptionsOKButtonClick;
    end;
  OptionsWindowForm.ActiveControl := OptionsOKButton;
  OptionsWindowForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

However, when running this, it gives the following error:

[image: Runtime Error]

I tried changing when this is called, by placing it after showing the window, but it doesn't get called until the window is closed, as `ShowModal` stops the scripts execution, when it still gives the same error. Is there a way to set a button to be focused in a modal window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is imo correct. It looks like a bug to me.

It's the setting of the `OptionsWindowForm.Parent` property that triggers the problem. Just remove it.

[image]