# Detect when button/control is focused in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to fire an event (for example updating a label) when a control (button) is focused.

Is there any trick doing this in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to implement due to a lack of `OnEnter` event in Inno Setup API (there are 3rd party Inno Setup clones that do have this functionality, not that I recommend using them).

The only solution, I know, is to periodically monitor the active control. For an example, see:
[Prevent button from receiving focus in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40494465/850848)

Comment: TESTED and works great.