# inno setup: How to play embedded video or music while running installer?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to create a sample installer, while installing that setup video/audio should be play in background, so that we can inform the features of our product in Video/Audio format.

I have gone through [`Inno media player`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/inno-media-player/) and 
Later on i went through [`this link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359859/playing-sound-during-an-inno-setup-install) .

But unfortunately i didn't succeeded. Am not very clear about how to embed flash screen in my installer.

Can any one have better idea about it, please update me.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [`Inno Media Player`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-media-player/wiki/Introduction?tm=6) for Unicode Inno Setup. It includes also example script showing how to play video files. `</self-promotion>`

Comment: Nice tag </self-promotion> !!! +1

Comment: @TLama i was downloaded your inno media player, that contains one example file and library. Then i copied that library in to " C:\Users\SafeSquid\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_InnoMediaPlayer 0.03.zip\ " after that i was given one video file library and audio file path accordingly. Then i started compilation the error was "

Reading [Code] section
Parsing [Files] section, line 7
   Reading version info: C:\Users\SafeSquid\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_InnoMediaPlayer 0.03.zip\MediaPlayer.dll
Compiling [Code] section
Compiler Error!
Line 16: Column 40: Unknown type 'WideString'

Comment: Like I said, it's for Unicode version of Inno Setup. You are using ANSI one (that you check in your IDE window title bar; there will be `(a)` at the end). You'd need to download and use [`this one`](http://i.imgur.com/ltyffhR.png). It's year 2014, where non Unicode software has no chance to live :-)

Comment: @TLama ohh i see!! thank you. let me try this . Is this will support to inno script studio ???

Comment: @TLama What about Bass Audio Library ?? for this also do i need to install inno unicode ?

Comment: Bass Audio Library you can use in both, ANSI and Unicode. There will be even some examples over here (like [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12360780/960757)).

Comment: That's nice.. i would use that .. ofcourse  your self promotion is really good :)

Comment: @TLama Hi..now am using bass.dll (actually its bassasio.dll) . up to compilation is ok but while running time it was showed  me "cannot import bassasio.dll at temp folder" do you have any idea?

Comment: Is that verbose error that you get ? You must be precise when describing your problem... However, I don't know. I might take a look, but not in this thread. On StackOverflow each problem has a separate question post, so if you want to get help, you should ask a new question. If you do so, post a verbose error message and all relevant information, like e.g. script that you are having. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the simplest way for displaying the video is to create new (external) window and put the WebControl in it.

WebControl is simple web frame which can contain any website - so you can view YouTube videos, Flash videos or gif animations or any web content.

With sound it is even easier: use BASS audio library or TLama's library.