# How to have a custom click sound on button click in Inno Setup (Back + Next + Cancel)?

Tags: audio, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to have button click sounds in Inno setup?

I mean a different for *"Back"*, *"Next"* and *"Cancel"*.

I know there might be some questions and also answers to them, but I'm new to this site and I need some help.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Inno Media Player](https://code.google.com/archive/p/inno-media-player/) to play sounds.

See question [Playing sound during an Inno Setup install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12359859/850848).

To trigger the sound on button clicks use a code like:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "next.mp3"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "back.mp3"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "cancel.mp3"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "MediaPlayer.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

type
  TDirectShowEventProc = procedure(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);

function DSInitializeAudioFile(
  FileName: string; CallbackProc: TDirectShowEventProc): Boolean;
  external 'DSInitializeAudioFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSPlayMediaFile: Boolean;
  external 'DSPlayMediaFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
function DSStopMediaPlay: Boolean;
  external 'DSStopMediaPlay@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';

function GetTickCount: DWORD;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';      

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
end;

var
  PageChanged: DWORD;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  PageChanged := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure DirectShowEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);
begin
  { dummy }
end;

procedure PlaySound(FileName: string);
begin
  DSStopMediaPlay;
  ExtractTemporaryFile(FileName);

  if DSInitializeAudioFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\') + FileName, @DirectShowEvent) then
  begin
    DSPlayMediaFile;
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { NextButtonClick is called even for skipped pages (like the Welcome page) and }
  { during silent installs. To detect that, we check if at least half }
  { second elapsed since the page was shown }
  if GetTickCount - PageChanged > 500 then
  begin
    PlaySound('next.mp3');
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

function BackButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  PlaySound('back.mp3');
  Result := True;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  PlaySound('cancel.mp3');
end;
```